# How to open College Network Server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

My question might sound ridiculous, as I have no idea what exactly to ask, so please bear with it.
In our college, we have a central server, that we all access.

Various ways we can open it when I am on Windows are:

1. It shows up when we open `Network` and then by simply opening it, we can read/write contents to it.
2. Type `Ctrl + R` and then type `\\172.16.0.18` (our server), and it opens up.

However, I have no idea how to open it on Ubuntu???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the **`smbclient`** package, and you will be able to connect to `172.16.0.18` using ***Places → Connect to Server*** in Ubuntu (or by opening `smb://172.16.0.18` in the file manager). Alternatively, run `gvfs-mount smb://172.16.0.18` in Terminal.

To see the computer list under *Network*, you may need to install **`samba`** too. (Its `nmbd` component handles network browsing and Windows-compatible name resolution.)

Answer (score 0):

Install smbclient and smbfs. If you want to view shares graphically, try installing linneighborhood or pyneighborhood.

Then, from the application "Terminal," run `smbclient -L 172.16.0.18 -U%`

That should give you a list of shares that you could access.

Then, you need to run:

`sudo smbmount //172.16.0.18/Folder /home/username/whereiwanttomountto -o username=myusername,password=passwordofchoice,uid=1000,mask=000`

Comment: `smbfs` is obsolete and is replaced by `cifs`.